# about a BeanCurrentlyInCreationException, unresolvable circular reference

Tags: spring, hibernate, cxf

Good afternoon, I have a project based on apache-cxf v 2.5.2, spring 2.5.6 and hibernate v v 3.2.1. I'm using annotations to mark the units and objects I persist and am having a problem when deploying the war. Giving me the following exception:
**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storeService': Can not resolve reference to bean 'storeService' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'storeService': Requested bean is Currently in creation: is there an unresolvable loop reference?**

**this is the applicationContext.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
       ">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.aironman.core" />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:hibernate.properties"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>
                hibernate.dialect=${database.hibernate.dialect}
                hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
                hibernate.show_sql=true
                hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
                hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=0
                hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
                hibernate.default_schema=${hibernate.default_schema}
                hibernate.generate_statistics=true
                hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries=true
            </value>
        </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.aironman.core.pojos.Usuario</value>
                <value>com.aironman.core.pojos.Item</value>
                <value>com.aironman.core.pojos.Persona</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**this is beans.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
        <!-- DECLARACION DE LOS ENDPOINTS DE LOS WEB SERVICES-->
        <jaxws:endpoint
      id="storeService" implementor="#storeService"
      implementorClass="com.aironman.core.cxf.service.StoreServiceImpl"
      address="/Store" />
</beans>
```

both files are included on **web.xml**

this is implementation end point web service, storeService:

```
**@Service("storeService")
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.aironman.core.cxf.service.StoreService")
public class StoreServiceImpl implements StoreService** {

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(StoreServiceImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("servicioUsuarios")
    private ServicioUsuarios            servicioUsuarios;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("servicioItems")
    private ServicioItems               servicioItems;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("servicioApuntes")
    private ServicioApuntesContables    servicioApuntesContables;
    [B]public StoreServiceImpl()[/B]{
        log.info("CONSTRUCTOR SIN tipo StoreServiceImpl...");
    }
some methods... getters and setters ...
}
```

this is ServicioUsuariosImpl file:

```
package com.aironman.core.service;
**@Service("servicioUsuarios")
public class ServicioUsuariosImpl implements ServicioUsuarios** {
    private static ConcurrentHashMap <String,Usuario>hashMapUsuarios = new ConcurrentHashMap <String,Usuario> () ;
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ServicioUsuariosImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("servicioEncriptacion")
    private ServicioEncriptacion                    servicioEncriptacion;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("servicioPersistenciaUsuarios")
    private ServicioPersistenciaUsuarios            servicioPersistenciaUsuarios;
    public ServicioUsuariosImpl(){
        log.info("Constructor SIN tipo ServicioUsuariosImpl...");
        //TODO pendiente cargar el mapa con una llamada al servicioPersistencia
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void init()
    {
        log.info("init method on ServicioUsuariosImpl. Initializing hashMap...");
        //i need to call persistence layer to fill the hashMap        
    }
    some methods, getters and setters
}
```

As you can see, this service has inyected a persistent service called servicioPersistenciaUsuarios, which basically uses a dao marked as @repository.

this is ServicioPersistenciaUsuariosImpl implementation file:

```
package com.aironman.core.service;
**@Service("servicioPersistenciaUsuarios")
public class ServicioPersistenciaUsuariosImpl implements ServicioPersistenciaUsuarios** {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("usuarioHibernateDao")
    private UsuarioHibernateDao usuarioHibernateDao;
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ServicioPersistenciaUsuariosImpl.class);
    public ServicioPersistenciaUsuariosImpl()
    {
        log.info("Constructor ServicioPersistenciaUsuariosImpl...");
    }
    some methods, getters and setters
}
```

this is usuarioHibernateDao implementation file:

```
package com.aironman.core.hibernate;
**@Repository
public class UsuarioHibernateDao extends HibernateGenericDao<Usuario, String> implements UsuarioDao**
{
            private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UsuarioHibernateDao.class);
        [B]@Autowired
        public UsuarioHibernateDao(@Qualifier("sessionFactory")   SessionFactory sessionFactory) [/B]{
            super(sessionFactory);
        }
        some methods...         
}
```

ServicioUsuariosImpl has another dependencie, servicioEncriptacion, and as you may see, this is the implementation:

```
package com.aironman.core.service;
@Service("servicioEncriptacion")
public class ServicioEncriptacionImpl implements ServicioEncriptacion
{
      private static final String  algoritmo = "SHA-256";
      private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ServicioEncriptacionImpl.class);
      private static java.security.MessageDigest diggest ;
      [B]public ServicioEncriptacionImpl()[/B]
      {some code...
      }
      some methods...
    }
```

this is ServicioItemsImpl implementation file, another dependencie belongs to StoreServiceImpl.

```
package com.aironman.core.service;
**@Service("servicioItems")
public class ServicioItemsImpl implements ServicioItems**{
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap 
            <String,com.aironman.core.pojos.Item>
            //La pk es el isbn del item
            hashMapItems = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,com.aironman.core.pojos.Item>() ;
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ServicioItemsImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("servicioPersistenciaItems")
    private ServicioPersistenciaItems servicioPersistenciaItems;
    [B]public ServicioItemsImpl()[/B]
    {
        log.info("Constructor SIN TIPO ServicioItemsImpl");    
    }
    [B]@PostConstruct
    public void init()[/B]
    {
        log.info("init method on ServicioItemsImpl. Initializing hashMap...");
    }
    some methods, getters and setters
}
```

this is servicioPersistenciaItems implementation file:

```
package com.aironman.core.service;

@Service("servicioPersistenciaItems")
public class ServicioPersistenciaItemsImpl implements ServicioPersistenciaItems
{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("itemHibernateDao")
    private ItemHibernateDao itemHibernateDao;
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ServicioPersistenciaItemsImpl.class);    
    [B]public ServicioPersistenciaItemsImpl()[/B]
    {
        log.info("Constructor SIN tipo ServicioPersistenciaItemsImpl...");
    }
some methods, getters and setters...
}
```

and finish, ServicioApuntesContablesImpl implementation file, with no dependencies

```
package com.aironman.core.service;
[B]@Service("servicioApuntes")
public class ServicioApuntesContablesImpl implements ServicioApuntesContables[/B]{

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ServicioApuntesContablesImpl.class);
    private static ConcurrentHashMap <ClaveApunteContable,ApunteContable> mapaApuntesContables
                      = new ConcurrentHashMap <ClaveApunteContable,ApunteContable> ();

    //TODO al final tendre que persistir los apuntes contables, por ahora los mantendre en memoria...
    [B]public ServicioApuntesContablesImpl()[/B]
    {}
    some methods
}
```

in short, the problem is happening when Spring tries to instantiate the endpoint implementation file storeService and do not understand it because I have no typed constructor in any of the files, getters and setters I have the right and above any dependence is used to each other. Can someone please help me and explain what is happening? thank you very much

PD i have not put some code for readability issues and i easyly reach limit caracters, if someone needs to watch, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i allready solved my problem. Inside the endpoints.xml file a declared my ws with a id and  i d already have declared the implementation ws file with a @Service annotation, so the exception is now clear to me...